# Apache Airflow does not enforce dagrun_timeout

Tags: airflow

I am using Apache Airflow version 1.10.3 with the sequential executor, and I would like the DAG to fail after a certain amount of time if it has not finished. I tried setting `dagrun_timeout` in the example code

```py
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

default_args = {
    'owner': 'me',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2019, 6, 1),
    'retries': 0,
}

dag = DAG('min_timeout', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=5), dagrun_timeout = timedelta(seconds=30), max_active_runs=1)

t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='fast_task',
    bash_command='date',
    dag=dag)

t2 = BashOperator(
    task_id='slow_task',
    bash_command='sleep 45',
    dag=dag)

t2.set_upstream(t1)
```

`slow_task` alone takes more than the time limit set by `dagrun_timeout`, so my understanding is that airflow should stop DAG execution. However, this does not happen, and slow_task is allowed to run for its entire duration. After this occurs, the run is marked as failed, but this does not kill the task or DAG as desired. Using `execution_timeout` for `slow_task` does cause the task to be killed at the specified time limit, but I would prefer to use an overall time limit for the DAG rather than specifying `execution_timeout` for each task.

Is there anything else I should try to achieve this behavior, or any mistakes I can fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Airflow scheduler [runs a loop](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.3/airflow/jobs.py#L1499) at least every `SCHEDULER_HEARTBEAT_SEC` (the default is [5 seconds](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.3/airflow/config_templates/default_airflow.cfg#L461)).

Bear in mind `at least` here, because the scheduler performs some actions that may delay the next cycle of its loop.

These actions include:

- parsing the dags
- filling up the DagBag
- checking the DagRun and updating their state
- scheduling next DagRun

In your example, the delayed task isn't terminated at the `dagrun_timeout` because the scheduler performs its next cycle after the task completes.

Comment: Is your last sentence, true, though? In this example if I modified OP code to have `t2 >> t1` then when `t2` finishes the `dagrun_timeout` has been exceeded but DAG isn't failing. I'm also not manually triggering in my tests either.

Answer (score 4):

According to Airflow [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.5/_api/airflow/models/dag/index.html):

> `dagrun_timeout` (datetime.timedelta) – specify how long a DagRun should be up before timing out / failing, so that new DagRuns can be created. The timeout is only enforced for scheduled DagRuns, and only once the # of active DagRuns == max_active_runs.

So `dagrun_timeout` wouldn't work for non-scheduled DagRuns (e.g. manually triggered) and if the number of active DagRuns < `max_active_runs` parameter.